# UICollectionView missing some cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to make my custom calendar. And the problem is that after applying my custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout some of the cells started to disappear, while first section is looking good, but others are not.

**Section 1**

[image: Section 1]

**Section 2**

[image: Section 2]

This is a code for my flowLayout class.

```
class CalendarFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let layoutAttributesForCells = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    return recountedAttributesForCell(layoutAttributesForCells)
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?.map {
        attributes in
        let copiedAttributes = attributes.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        return recountedAttributesForCell(copiedAttributes)
    }

}

func recountedAttributesForCell(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    if let collectionView = self.collectionView {

        let sectionOffset = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.section) * collectionView.frame.height

        let itemsPerRow : CGFloat = 7
        let cellSize : CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width / itemsPerRow
        attributes.size = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)

        let xOffset : CGFloat = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.item % 7) * cellSize
        var yOffset : CGFloat = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.item / 7) * cellSize
        yOffset += sectionOffset

        attributes.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
    }
    return attributes
}
}
```